# не работают ссылки в хедере

Tags: html, css, slider, site

У меня не работают ссылки в хедере, но когда удаляю слайдер то все нормально работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить данну[image: <code>введите сюда описание изображения</code>]ю проблему

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 outline: none;
 overflow: none;
}

body, html {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: none;
}

body {
 background-color: #fff;
 font-family: Comfortaa, Russo One;
 overflow: none;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: inherit;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 ,h6 {
 background-color: #fff;
 font-family: Russo One, serif;
}

/* header */

header {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 10px 0.5% 0px 0.5%;
 background: transparent;
 float: left;
 font-family: Russo One, serif;
 background-color: #CC0000;
 background-color: #00C4FE;
}

header .logo img {
 padding-top: 5px;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 15%;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 height: 70px;
}

header .logo_2 img {
 float: left;
 width: 11%;
 margin-left: 70px;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
}


header .about a {
 position: relative;
 top: 8px;
 word-spacing: 2px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
    margin-right: 40px;
}

.links {
 display:block;
 align-items: center;
 font-size: 23px;
 top: 32px;
 left: 22%;
 word-spacing: 10px;
 position: absolute;
}


#word {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 right: 20px;
 top: 50px;
 color: #fff;

 margin-bottom: 20px;
 line-height: 10px;
 font-size: 23px;

}

/* slider */

#slider { position: relative;
text-align: center;}

#slider{ margin: 0 auto;}

#slides article{width: 20%;float: left;}

#slides .image{ 
 width: 500%;
 line-height: 0;
 background-color: #fff;
}

#overflow{ width: 100%;overflow: hidden;}

article img{
 width: 100%;
 height: 550px;
 float: left;
}

#desktop:checked ~ #slider{ max-width: none; }

#switch1:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(5), 
#switch2:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(1),
#switch3:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(2),
#switch4:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(3),
#switch5:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(4){
 background: url('../img/4.png') no-repeat; 
 float: left;
 margin: 0 0 0 -84px;
 height: 68px;
 width: 68px;
}

#switch1:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(2), 
#switch2:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(3),
#switch3:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(4),
#switch4:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(5),
#switch5:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(1){
 background: url('../img/4.png') no-repeat; 
 float: right;
 margin: 0 -84px 0 0; 
 display: block;
 height: 68px;
 width: 68px;
}

label, a{cursor: pointer;}

.all input{display: none;}


#switch1:checked ~ #slides .image{margin-left: 0;}

#switch2:checked ~ #slides .image{margin-left: -100%;}

#switch3:checked ~ #slides .image{margin-left: -200%;}

#switch4:checked ~ #slides .image{margin-left: -300%;}

#switch5:checked ~ #slides .image{margin-left: -400%;}

#controls{ 
 margin: -25% 0 0 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
}

#active label{ 
 border-radius: 20px; 
 display: inline-block; 
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 background: #fff;
 border: 4px solid #f1f1f1;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 35em;
}

#active{ 
 margin: 23% 0 0;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #fff;
}

#active label:hover{ 
 background: #fff;
 border-color: #f9f9f9 !important; 
}

#switch1:checked ~ #active label:nth-child(1),
#switch2:checked ~ #active label:nth-child(2),
#switch3:checked ~ #active label:nth-child(3),
#switch4:checked ~ #active label:nth-child(4),
#switch5:checked ~ #active label:nth-child(5){
 background: #fff;
 border-color: #dddddd !important;
}

#slides .image{ 
 transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
}

#controls label:hover{ 
 opacity: 0.6;
}

#controls label{ 
 transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
   <img src="img/1.png" alt="Махаон центр обучения">
  </div>
  <div class="logo_2">
   <img src="img/2.png" alt="Горячие клавиши">
   
  </div>
  <div class="about">
   <div class="links">
         <a href="#" title="Главная">Главная</a>
         <a href="#" title="Новости">Новости</a>
         <a href="#" title="Галерея">Галерея</a>
         <a href="#" title="Контакты">Контакты</a>
      </div>
   <a id="word">Положение</a>
  </div>
  </header>
 <div class="all">
  <input checked type="radio" name="respond" id="desktop">
   <article id="slider">
     <input checked type="radio" name="slider" id="switch1">
     <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch2">
     <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch3">
     <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch4">
     <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch5">
    <div id="slides">
     <div id="overflow">
      <div class="image">
       <article><img src="img/6.png"></article>
       <article><img src="img/3.jpg"></article>
       <article><img src="img/1.jpg"></article>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="controls">
     <label for="switch1"></label>
     <label for="switch2"></label>
     <label for="switch3"></label>
     <label for="switch4"></label>
     <label for="switch5"></label>
    </div>
    <div id="active">
     <label for="switch1"></label>
     <label for="switch2"></label>
     <label for="switch3"></label>
    </div>
   </article>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас слайдер "залез" поверх шапки.
пропишите слайдеру свойство `clear: both;`

```css
#slider{
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромной, хороший человек))